# Catch IOException for invalid input

Tags: java, android

I am creating a Tip calculator app..where I accept inputs from users in terms of total amount. I want add an exception to the code where it would Toast a message if the User does not enter a valid number. I have three buttons and have created different methods for every button. I am pasting the code below for the one of the buttons i.e. 10% tip

```
private void CalculateTipListener(){
        BtnTip10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                double amount = Double.parseDouble(etTotalAmount.getText().toString());
                double TipAmount=amount/10;
                tvTipAmount.setText("Tip: $"+TipAmount);
                } catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

Error logs give me a NumberFormatException error.

```
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "gagajgalk"
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at com.example.tipcalculator.TipCalculatorActivity$2.onClick(TipCalculatorActivity.java:47)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-12 20:10:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone please let me know how to handle the exceptions in such a scenario? I was trying the Toast method but it doesn't seem to work since I have used anonymous classes within every method/listener.

Thanks.

/rd

Comment: why does the Toast method not work?

Comment: `The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, String, int)`  This is the error I get when I use Toast.

Comment: Why are you catching `IOException`? The exception thrown is `NumberFormatException`

Comment: @A--C - I tried using `NumberFormatException` too, but it doesnt seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @rond Are you sure? I made an answer showing how the code should look like. Try it out and if it still crashes, tell us the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch `NumberFormatException` instead of `IOException` (refer to the stack trace).

```
private void CalculateTipListener(){
        BtnTip10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                double amount = Double.parseDouble(etTotalAmount.getText().toString());
                double TipAmount=amount/10;
                tvTipAmount.setText("Tip: $"+TipAmount);
                } catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    Toast.makeText (v.getContext(), "Invalid input!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
    });
```

Additionally (since the problem was more about making the `Toast` rather than the Exception)
Once you are working inside an anonymous inner class (like that `OnClickListener`, `this` will refer to that class. If you wanted to access the outer activity instance to pass it off to the Toast, you could explicitly call it using `ActivityName.this`.

You can also use [`View#getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29) since you already have a View object passed to the method.

Comment: Ok this seemed to work `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`. I was using `this` and I guess that should have worked too. I haven't come across `v.getContext()` before.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you also need to explicitly catch the NumberFormatException, ie:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    ...
}
```

Also you should consider adding some rules like trim()'ing the input string, and validating the input string is not null/empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the IOException to NumberFormatException that you can resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are catching an [<kbd>IOException</kbd>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html), but you need to catch a [<kbd>NumberFormatException</kbd>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html), which is even states in your stacktrace (please read it).

So you can change this:

```
catch(IOException e)
```

to this

```
catch(NumberFormatException e)
```

---

Extra notes:

To catch *any* error, use [<kbd>Exception</kbd>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html):

```
catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Error.");
}
```

---

You can combine these to catch different errors so you can handle them separately. For example:

```
try 
{
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(etTotalAmount.getText().toString());
    double TipAmount=amount/10;
    tvTipAmount.setText("Tip: $"+TipAmount);
}
catch (NumberFormatException n) {
    // they didn't enter a number
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number.", 0).show();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // there is another, unspecified, exception
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unspecified exception.", 0).show();
}
```